# Converse of Banach fixed-point theorem

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

**Banach fixed-point theorem** states that:

If $(X,d)$ - complete metric space and $f:X\to X$ is contraction mapping. Then exists unique point $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=x_0.$

And I have the following question:

*Is there incomplete metric space in which every contraction mapping has fixed point?*

Can anyone give link to proof of this problem please?

I thought on this problem some hours but I haven't any ideas. I guess that it's really hard problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Contraction mapping in an incomplete metric space](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/contraction-mapping-in-an-incomplete-metric-space)

Comment: The example by [Suzuki and Takahashi](https://www.tmna.ncu.pl/static/files/v08n2-11.pdf) *$S = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n \cup \{0\}$, where  $A_n = \{(t, t/n) | t \in (0,1]\}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. S is not complete and every continuous mapping on $S$ has a fixed point in S*.

Comment: @Weaam, Can I ask you couple questions? 1) Why $S$ is not complete? 2) He proves that every continuous mapping has fixed point. Consequently every contraction mapping also has fixed point. Am I right?

Comment: @Weaam, Why $A_j\cup \{0\}$ is convex and compact?

Comment: - $S$ is not complete because $(1,1/n) \to (1,0) \notin S$. 
- For $A_j \cup \{0\}$, here $j$ is fixed, so it is the image of $f(t) = \{(t,t/j)$ with domain the closed interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Weaam, So what? Sorry but how we conclude from here that $A_j\cup \{0\}$ is convex and compact?

Comment: For a fixed $j$, can you show that $f_j(t) : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $f_j(t) = (t,t/j)$ is continuous? Then it will follow that $f_j([0,1])$ is also compact.

Comment: @Weaam, Yes I can. Both $t$ and $t/j$ are continuous on $[0,1]$. Hence $(t,t/j)$ is also continuous on $[0,1]$. Maybe you mean that "$f_j([0,1])$" is also compact?

Comment: Is convexity of $f_j([0,1])$ note clear? In any case, if $L_1=(t_1, t_1/j), L_2 = (t_2, t_2/j)$ in $A_j \cup \{0\}$, then $t_x = (1-x)t_1+t_2 \in [0,1]$ and thus $L_1 + x(L_2-L_1) = (t_x, t_x/j) \in A_j \cup \{0\}$.

Comment: @Weaam. Thanks a lot for your help! Wish you the best! :)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't going through the details, but I think you can find the answer in [this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.5920) and article cited.