# Completeness can be omitted from Banach Fixed Point Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-fixed-point

In Kreyszig's Functional Analysis, page no. 303, exercise no. 3 says that completeness cannot be omitted from Banach's Fixed Point Theorem. But if we take $f(x)=x^2$ from an incomplete metric space $(-1/3,1/3)$ to $(-1/3,1/3)$, here $f$ is a contraction and this $f$ has a unique fixed point $0$. Here I have omitted completeness but I am still getting a unique fixed point - where am I wrong?

Banach's Fixed Point Theorem:
Consider a non-empty metric space $X = (X, d)$. Suppose that $X$ is
complete and let $T: X \to X$ be a contraction on $X$. Then $T$ has precisely
one fixed point.

Comment: Somewhat related:
[Converse to Banach's fixed point theorem?](http://mathoverflow.net/q/26119) and
[Contraction mapping in an incomplete metric
space](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/67490)

Comment: The negation of "for all ... then ... is true" is "there exists some ... such that ... is false", not "for all ... then ... is false".

Comment: Another way of phrasing Najib's comment is that theorems generally say "if these conditions are met, then this result holds".  If the conditions aren't met, then the result may or may not hold; we can't tell.  Kreyszig is asking you to find an example where the conditions aren't met and the result doesn't hold.  You've found an example where the conditions aren't met and the result still holds.  Which is cool, but not what is being asked.

Comment: Note that a contraction $T$ on any metric space $X$ extends in a unique way to a contraction on the completion $\bar X$, so there is always a unique fixed point $x_0 \in \bar X$. If $x_0 \in \bar X \setminus X$, then $T$ does not have a fixed point in $X$.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

"Completeness can't be omitted" is just saying that if $X$ is not complete, you can't be certain that a fixed point will exist for any given function. It doesn't mean you will never find one for specific functions.

It's like saying that "if $X$ is not complete, not all cauchy sequences converge". But you can definitely find some cauchy squences that do converge.

**EDIT**
It's now interesting to investigate how the theorem fails without completeness:

Firstly, here's an example of a contraction defined on a non-complete metric space with no fixed point:

$f:(0,1)\rightarrow(0,1)$ such that $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{2}$.

Clearly this is a contraction because $|f(x)-f(y)|=\Big|\dfrac{x}{2}-\dfrac{y}{2}\Big| = \dfrac{1}{2}|x-y|$ for any $x, y \in (0, 1)$. However, for any $x\in(0,1)$, $f(x)\neq x$, so there is no fixed point.

(On the natural domain of the function, the fixed point would be at $0$, but you can see that this is on the boundary of our non-complete set.)

Secondly, are there any cases where the metric space being incomplete results in more than one fixed point? The answer is no. Suppose $f:X\rightarrow X$ is a contraction and $X$ is any metric space (complete or not complete). Suppose $f$ has two fixed points at $x$ and $y$. Then $|f(x)-f(y)| = |x - y|$. This contradicts the definition of a contraction which requires $|f(a)-f(b)|<|a-b|$ for all $a,b\in X$.

Comment: O nice, would you like to give an example of such a function which fails to have unique fixed point in incomplete metric space.

Comment: Sure, you need something that tries to approach a fixed point on the boundary of the set. I'll edit my answer and add an example.

Comment: any function which has two or more fixed points due to incompleteness?

Comment: The answer is no - I'll add this in an edit too.

Answer (score 7):

As well as Shanye2020's counterexample on an open interval, we can construct a counterexample on a closed subset of the rationals: take $M=[-\frac13,\frac13]\cap\mathbb Q$, and $f(x)=x^2+\frac16$. Then $f(x)$ has a fixed point in $[-\frac13,\frac13]$ as a subset of $\mathbb R$, but this fixed point is irrational.